# Return an array from function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to code a function that accepts an array as an argument.  Then the function fills some elements.  Finally, the array filled by the function becomes visible from the caller.

```
sub main1()
    Dim A(1,3) as string
    F(A) '???How to get the value of each array element here?
    ...
End Sub

Function F(X(1,3) as string) string()
    X(1,1)=3.14
End Function
```

I looked at the following post but did not get it, somehow the questions are not the same.

[return array from function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564846/return-array-from-function-in-vba)

Comment: use the variant data type in your method signature  Function Blah(myArray as Variant) as Variant

Comment: if you read the answers to the question you linked to carefully, you will see where you need to adjust your code.

Comment: @Sorceri, correct, defining F(X as VARIANT) AS VARIANT then assigning the call result to a Variant makes data appear inside the passed parameter!!! Thank you. I would mark this an answer if your comment as an answer.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, you may be right, I just could not see it!

Comment: @NoChance - It's tricky stuff, no doubt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to just pass the array ByRef

```
Sub main1()
    Dim A(1, 3) As String
    Call F(A)
    Debug.Print A(1, 1)
End Sub
Sub F(ByRef x() As String)
    x(1, 1) = 3.14
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly and I could use the original type without using a Variant. Very good.

Comment: @NoChance thanks. I also modified my answer slightly to change the Array populator as a Sub, not a Function as it returns no value.

Comment: This is also correct, thanks again. It is good idea to send data byRef for efficiency but it is harmful to let the called program to change it. Anyway, it looks like the universe has managed to survive without  my wisdom!