# Trying to return multiple values in a function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For a complex calculation I have written a VBA function. But ideally I would return more than one result during testing.

```
My_Function(someinput)
Result1 = "Result1"
Result2 = "Result2"
Result3 = "Result3"
Result4 = "Result4"
End Function
```

In a cell I would like to write:

```
=My_Function.Result1(someinput)
```

And the return would be:

```
"Result1"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: [Use an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564846/return-array-from-function-in-vba)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to get back one or Mutiple results to a single cell?

Comment: "I would return more than one result during testing" - why?  Can you expand on this a little?  In your example, why is "Result1" the expected return value?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have a function, that returns one of several possibilities. There is no syntax of the form you want, but you can easily achieve the same thing by having a second parameter which tells your function which return value is required

Comment: I want for debugging purposes to define which value I return from within the complex function. Now I am constantly changing the function output to a single value and not getting the full result

Comment: "I want for debugging purposes to define which value I return from within the complex function."  But it's very unclear how you want to be able to do that?  In your ideal scenario, what would that look like?  What kind of testing are you meaning?

Comment: Multiple ways to return multiple values from a Function.  Using an object, Type/struture, ByRef parameter and function returns a value eg. TryParse functions.  Function returning an arrray or Collections etc.  Also can return a value and/or raise an error.

Comment: For unit testing you might  want to check out https://rubberduckvba.com/    A VBA addin to help with code inspections and unit testing and various features.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can use is:

```
Function My_Function(someinput As Variant, selector As Integer) As Variant
  My_Function = Choose(selector, "Result1", "Result2", "Result3", "Result4")
End Function

=My_Function("asda"; 2) --> "Result2"
```

Another way is already mentioned returning of an array:

```
Function My_Function(someinput As Variant) As Variant
  Dim av As Variant
  ReDim av(3)
  av(0) = "Result1"
  av(1) = "Result2"
  av(2) = "Result3"
  av(3) = "Result4"
  My_Function = av
End Function

=My_Function("asda") --> { "Result1", "Result2", "Result3", "Result4" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a User Defined Type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement)

```
Type Results
    result1 As String
    result2 As String
    result3 As Long
End Type

Function myFunction(someInput As Variant) As Results
    myFunction.result1 = "Result1"
    myFunction.result2 = "Result2"
    myFunction.result3 = 15
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print myFunction("hi").result1
End Sub
```

This approach has the added benefit, that all return values are type checked.

Comment: This solution doesn't allow to use the function on a worksheet.